# Browser based testing with Phantom/Casper

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using casper to test the UI or websites. I would like to know if I can test their compatibility in different browsers like IE/Chrome/Firefox using casper. Also if it cant be done, is there any other way to do it without switching from casper?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to test multiple browsers, then I recommend using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

It's an extremely complicated product, however, and has a steep learning curve. But if you are serious about testing and QA then it's hard to beat. Perhaps break yourself in to it gently with the IDE.

Selenium also comes with a server that gives you the ability to offload testing to other machines on your network (possibly running a different OS for example) or even send a test over to a cloud service like [Testing Bot](http://www.testingbot.com/) or [SauceLabs](http://www.saucelabs.com/). They can test your web app in many different browsers and even provide you screenshots of each stage of the test, and a video to wrap it up. I believe both offer free trials.

I am not aware of any other phantom solutions like phantom-firefox or phantom-ie. Though it would be great if they existed.

Answer (score 1):

Casper uses `Phantomjs` as a driver (QtWebkit).

You can use `slimerjs` as driver if you want to test in Firefox (http://slimerjs.org/index.html).

Unfortunately for testing IE using `casperjs`, currently I don't think there are any solutions out there.